# intent action view inside start activity for result to implement Linkedin sign in api v2 with Oauth

Tags: android, android-intent, linkedin-api, onactivityresult

I want to implement Linkedin the new sign in Api v2 so I wanted to made for it a separate activity to launch it from any where with startActiivtyForResult() this activity is LinkedActivity then when LinkedActivity starts I call Intent action view to make Oauth2 for linkedin v2 api so when it gets back and finish getting my requested data I finish this activity and return where I was in the first time when I receiving the data in onActivityResult my result always Canceled and the back intent is NULL ! 
I have been searching for some cases like that or trying to debug my code in linkedin activity the returnintent has extras and all good
here is my code for finishing my linkedin activity for result

```
class LinkedActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var linkedInAuth: LinkedInAuth
    private var email = ""
    private var firstname = ""
    private var lastname = ""
    private var userId = ""
    private var accessToken = ""
    private val linkedInAuthUrl =
        "$authorizationUrl?response_type=code&client_id=$clinetId&redirect_uri=$redirectLink&scope=r_liteprofile,r_emailaddress"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_linked)
        if (intent.action == null) {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(linkedInAuthUrl))
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (intent.data != null) {
            val uri = intent.data
            if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(redirectLink)) {
                val code = uri.getQueryParameter("code")!!
                linkedInAuth = getRetrofitInstanse(LinkedInAuth.AUTH_URL).create(LinkedInAuth::class.java)
                val authTokenReq =
                    linkedInAuth.getAccessToken(LinkedInAuth.GRANT_TYPE, code, redirectLink, clinetId, clinetSecrect)
                authTokenReq.enqueue(object : Callback<LinkedinAccessTokenResponse> {
                    override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<LinkedinAccessTokenResponse>, response: Response<LinkedinAccessTokenResponse>
                    ) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful) {
                            val result: LinkedinAccessTokenResponse? = response.body()
                            if (result != null) {
                                accessToken = result.accessToken
                                fetchBasicProfileData(accessToken)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<LinkedinAccessTokenResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                        t.printStackTrace()
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * method to fetch basic profile data
     */
    private fun fetchBasicProfileData(accessToken: String) {
        linkedInAuth = getRetrofitInstanse(LinkedInAuth.BASE_URL).create(LinkedInAuth::class.java)
        val profileLiteRequest = linkedInAuth.getProfileData(LinkedInAuth.PROJECTION, "Bearer $accessToken")
        profileLiteRequest.enqueue(object : Callback<LinkedInLiteProfileResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<LinkedInLiteProfileResponse>, response: Response<LinkedInLiteProfileResponse>
            ) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val result: LinkedInLiteProfileResponse? = response.body()
                    if (result != null) {
                        firstname = result.firstName?.localized?.enUS!!
                        lastname = result.lastName?.localized?.enUS!!
                        userId = result.id!!
                        Log.d(TAG, "$firstname  $lastname   $userId")
                        getEmail()
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<LinkedInLiteProfileResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                t.printStackTrace()
            }
        })


    }

    fun getEmail() {
        val emailRequest = linkedInAuth.getEmaillAddress("members", "(elements*(handle~))", "Bearer $accessToken")
        emailRequest.enqueue(object : Callback<EmailResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<EmailResponse>, response: Response<EmailResponse>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val result: EmailResponse? = response.body()
                    if (result != null) {
                        email = result.elements[0].emailHandle?.email!!
                        Log.d(TAG, email)
                        val returnIntent = Intent()
                        returnIntent.putExtra("user_id", userId)
                        returnIntent.putExtra("first_name", firstname)
                        returnIntent.putExtra("last_name", lastname)
                        returnIntent.putExtra("user_email", email)
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)
                        finish()
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<EmailResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                t.printStackTrace()
            }
        })
    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG = LinkedActivity::class.java.simpleName
        private val clinetId = ""
        private val clinetSecrect = ""
        private val redirectLink = "https://signin-linkedin.com/auth/callback"
        private val authorizationUrl = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization"

    }

}
```

and this is my retrofit interface

```
interface LinkedInAuth {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("accessToken")
    fun getAccessToken(
        @Field("grant_type") grantType: String,
        @Field("code") code: String,
        @Field("redirect_uri") redirectUrl: String,
        @Field("client_id") clientId: String,
        @Field("client_secret") clientSecret: String
    ): Call<LinkedinAccessTokenResponse>

    @GET("me")
    fun getProfileData(
        @Query("projection") projection: String, @Header("Authorization") authorization: String
    ): Call<LinkedInLiteProfileResponse>

    @GET("emailAddress")
    fun getEmaillAddress(
        @Query("q") query: String, @Query("projection") projection: String,
        @Header("Authorization") authorization: String
    ): Call<EmailResponse>

    companion object {
        const val AUTH_URL = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/"
        const val BASE_URL = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/"
        const val GRANT_TYPE = "authorization_code"
        const val PROJECTION = "(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))"
    }
}

fun getRetrofitInstanse(baseUrl: String): Retrofit {
    val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    val okhttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
        .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(okhttpClient)
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
}

data class LinkedinAccessTokenResponse(
    @SerializedName("access_token") val accessToken: String,
    @SerializedName("expires_in") val expiresIn: String
)
```

and this is where I receive my result where it came back with null and result canceled

```
     override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED && requestCode != PICK_FILE)
                dialog.showErrorDialog(getString(R.string.fetch_data_error))
            if (requestCode == RC_FB_SIGN_IN)
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    socialProvider = "facebook"
                    updateUiFromSocial(data)
                }
            if (requestCode == RC_GPLUS_SIGN_IN)
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    socialProvider = "google"
                    updateUiFromSocial(data)
                }
            if (requestCode == RC_LNKD_SIGN_IN)
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    socialProvider = "linkedin"
                    updateUiFromSocial(data)
                }
}
```

**UPDATE**

when changing onResume() into onNewIntent() and make LinkedActivity launch mode into single top every thins works just fine

Comment: `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` does not return a result . You need to load that URL in a Web View and intercept the loading with `WebViewClient` . Well this is how i used LinkedIn auth way back 3 years ago. I am not sure if they have changed it .

Comment: You are expecting a result back from a browser . Thats not possible . And You didn't even called `startActivityForResult` which does not ,matter either ..

Comment: the question is can I make ACTION_VIEW from activity which is started for result? then return back to my where I fired that activity?

Comment: Already answered your question . You can't ..

Comment: I called startActivityForResult from another place so LinkedActivity is the activity I fired ....

Comment: when changing onResume() into onNewIntent() and make LinkedActivity launch mode into single top every thins works just fine so I think you understand my question wrong